# Regex issue removes \n while parsing

Tags: java, regex, newline

There is an existing regex in my code which is `[^\s"']+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'`. My problem is that when i do something like:

```
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("INDIA \n PAKISTAN");
  StringBuilder returnQuery = new StringBuilder();
  while (matcher.find()) {
      String str = matcher.group();
      if (AND.equalsIgnoreCase(str) || OR.equalsIgnoreCase(str) || NOT.equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
          returnQuery.append(str.toUpperCase()).append(" ");
      } else {
          returnQuery.append(str).append(" ");
      }
  }
```

it removed the \n characters as well which i want to retain, Can someone please suggesta solution.

Appreciate the help in advance

Vaibhav

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The \s metacharacter is used to find a whitespace character.
       A whitespace character can be:

- A space character
- A tab character
- A carriage return character
- A **new line** character
- A vertical tab character
- A form feed character

So you if you are using \s you are out of luck. Just use a character class without \n e.g.

```
[ \r\t]
```

This way your \n will be retained.